# How to add only clicked check box position

Tags: android, listview

I have contacts in my app.

Here contacts are in List View and which will be selected using the check box click.

I don't know what is the problem here. It adds all the contacts in list view while clicking the add button.It doesn't consider the check box click.

Please help me to find the solution...

```
   public class ContactActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

        private Gson gson = new Gson();


        private ContactDispAdapter contactDispAdapter;
        private Button btnAdd;
        private Button btnSend;
        private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
        UserDelegate userDelegate = new UserDelegate();
        private Context context;
        private HashMap<String, UserMO> userMosMapAll = new HashMap<>();
        private ArrayList<UserMO> userMOs = new ArrayList<>();
        private UserMO userMO = new UserMO();
        private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
        private String eventId;


        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onPause();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contactslistmain);
            context = getApplicationContext();
            sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           // default value of sharedpreference is null if no event id found default value null is returned
            eventId = sharedpreferences.getString("eventId","null");
            Toast.makeText(context, "contact String" + eventId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.remove("eventId");
            editor.commit();
            // in contact page click load button get all contacts from device and
            // send to server and return matching user
            // remove old values from list
            // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
            prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            // Set Progress Dialog Text
            prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            // Set Cancelable as False
            prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
            prgDialog.show();
            final String[] mobileNumbers = Utility.getAllContacts(context.getContentResolver());
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    return userDelegate.getMatchingExistingUserList(mobileNumbers, context);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String contactList) {
                    if (contactList != "null") {
                        userMOs = gson.fromJson(contactList, new TypeToken<List<UserMO>>() {
                        }.getType());
                        for (UserMO userMO : userMOs) {
                            userMosMapAll.put(userMO.getMobileNumber(), userMO);
                        }

                        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                        prgDialog.dismiss();
                        ListView contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_List_view);
                        contactDispAdapter = new ContactDispAdapter();
                        contactListView.setAdapter(contactDispAdapter);
                        contactListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                        contactListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(contactListView.getOnItemClickListener());
                    }

                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);


            btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Contact_Add);
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
                    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContactActivity.this);
                    // Set Progress Dialog Text
                    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                    // Set Cancelable as False
                    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

                    prgDialog.show();
                    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                    // by default first primary user is current user in sql lite
                    // user table
                    final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
                    System.out.println(".............." + contactDispAdapter.mCheckStates.size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < userMOs.size(); i++) {
                        if (contactDispAdapter.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                            if (userMosMapAll.containsKey(userMOs.get(i).getMobileNumber())) {
                                userMOs.add(userMosMapAll.get(userMOs.get(i).getMobileNumber()));
                            }
                            System.out.println("Checked......" + userMOs.get(i).getMobileNumber());
                        } else
                        {

                            System.out.println("Not Checked......" + userMOs.get(i).getMobileNumber());
                        }
                    }
                    if (userMOs.size() != 0 && contactDispAdapter.mCheckStates.size()!=0) {
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            @Override
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.addEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMOs, eventId);
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "response is " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                prgDialog.dismiss();
                                Intent userDashBoardAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserDashBoardActivity.class);
                                // Clears History of Activity
                                userDashBoardAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(userDashBoardAct);
                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                    }else {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Atleast invite one more person to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            contactDispAdapter.toggle(arg2);
        }

        // add name and mobile number in adapter to show in contact page
        private class ContactDispAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
            private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            TextView mobileNumTxtV, userNameTxtV;
            CheckBox cb;

            ContactDispAdapter() {
                mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(userMOs.size());
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return userMOs.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            // show list values name and mobile number in contact page
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi = convertView;
                if (convertView == null)
                    vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist, null,false);
                userNameTxtV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
                mobileNumTxtV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number);
                cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                userNameTxtV.setText(userMOs.get(position).getUserName());
                mobileNumTxtV.setText(userMOs.get(position).getMobileNumber());
                cb.setTag(position);
                cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

                return vi;
            }

            public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
            }
        }
    }
```

After CheckBox click(contact list) I need to click add button.

Inside byn_add click listener I need clicked check box position to to UserMOs and pass that to add `userDelegate.addEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMOs, eventId);`

Please help me to find....

Comment: Add/Remove the contacts when checked/unchecked from arraylist. And then on ADD button click get the contacts from arraylist and display them.

Comment: i dont know how to do that..i am new to android..can u please help me

Comment: check out this tutorial: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html